# Discriminant of a monic quartic polynomial

Tags: discriminant

I'm having trouble understanding a part of the proof for the final theorem of this article https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0017089506003272.

The discriminant of $g(x)=x^4+px^2+qx+r$ is

$-27p^4-108p^3q-162p^2q^2-108pq^3-27q^4+256r^3$

We can rewrite $f(x)=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d = (x+\frac{a}{4})^4+(b-\frac{3}{8}a^2)x^2+(c-\frac{a^3}{16})x+(d-\frac{a^4}{256})$.

If we let

$p= b-\frac{3}{8}a^2$, $q=c-\frac{a^3}{16}$ and $r= d-\frac{a^4}{256}$ then the discriminant of $f$ is

$2^{24} \cdot(-27p^4-108p^3q-162p^2q^2-108pq^3-27q^4+256r^3)$

I don't understand why this is true since $f$ does not have the same shape as $g$ because of $(x+\frac{a}{4})^4$.

Also, where did the constant $2^{24}$ come from? Does it depend on the linear transformation $x \mapsto x+\frac{a}{4}$? Does it have to do with the fact that the discriminant is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $2n-2=2(4)-2=6$ in the coefficients of $f$?

Comment: The substitution $x\leftarrow x+\dfrac a4$ doesn't change the discriminant, so we are free to do it, and use the (simpler) formula for the discriminant of the depressed quartic. I assume that the factor $2^{24}$ is added just to clear the denominators in a minimal way. This may play a role in e.g. number theoretic applications.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, the substitution $x \rightarrow x+a/4$ does not change the discriminant. However, only one x is substituted, the first term in particular. The other x remain the same. Does that change the discriminant or not?

Comment: This means that you're saying 'the discriminant of $x^4+px^2+qx+r$ is the same as $(x+a/4)^4+px^2+qx+r$?'

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Something strange is going on.

Answer (score 1):

The discriminant of $f$ is the same as the discriminant of
$f(x-a/4)$. The discriminant is the product of differences of zeros
of the polynomial, so doesn't change when these zeros are all translated
by the same amount.

Dietmann does **not** assert that the formula with the $2^{24}$
factor is the discriminant. Rather that is a square integer and
when you multiply it by the discriminant it cancels off all the
powers of two in the denominators, yielding an expression (i)
which is an integer if $a,\ldots,d$ are integers, and (ii) is
a square iff the discriminant is a square.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you meant 'f has the same discriminant as f(x+a/4)' instead of 'f(x+a/4)'?

Comment: Also, not all x substitute into x+a/4, only the first term. Doesn't that make a difference?

Comment: @Tasmia It looks as if Dietmann made a blunder. He should have replaced $x$ by $x+a/4$ throughout. Then one would get more complicated formulae for $q$ and $r$. I don't think that would affect the rest of his arguments. Perhaps you should write to him?