# In $\mathbb R^3$ with coordinates $a,b,c,$ sketch the surface whose points represent polynomials $x^4 + ax^2 + bx + c$ with multiple roots.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, roots, surfaces, discriminant

I have to solve the following question:

> In $\mathbb R^3$ with coordinates $a,b,c,$ sketch the surface (the discriminant) whose points represent polynomials $x^4 + ax^2 + bx + c$ with multiple roots.

As a hint to the question, we are also given the following:

> Examine the curve formed by the polynomials $(x − t)^3(x + 3t)$ having a triple root, and show that the discriminant consists of
> the lines tangent to this curve.

I can't even begin to understand what the question is asking for, how to begin, or even if it's feasible to draw/sketch such a surface. I'd appreciate any help at this point.

Edit: Sorry for the lack of proper info, I genuinely do not know what the "discriminant" is referring to as well, but my best guess is the following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant

1. Comment 1: Cannot use any explicit discriminant formula.
2. Comment 2: It's only asking us to sketch the surface.
3. Definition: Multiple roots means the multiplicity of the root.
4. Definition: discriminant of a polynomial is a quantity that depends on
   the coefficients and determines various properties of the roots.
5. Definition: discriminant is either positive, zero, or negative.
6. Definition: R^3 is the three dimensional space.
7. Definition: Multiple roots consists of repeated two roots, triple
   roots, four roots, etc.
8. Definition: Tangent lines is to a plane curve at a given point is the
   straight line that "just touches" the curve at that point.

Comment: Right now this is a [no-clue question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27923/how-to-prevent-no-clue-questions) and needs improvement. Can you write down the definition of the discriminant? Can you compute the discriminant of $x^4+ax^2+bx+c$? Do you know what the discriminant has to do with multiple roots?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact (strongly connected to the notion of discriminant) that "being a multiple root of p" is equivalent to "being at the same time a root of p and a root of p' (its derivative)" ?

Comment: @KReiser I have added an edit, sorry.

Comment: @JeanMarie Wow, i did not know that fact. I'll try to look it up.

Comment: @KReiser In response to your inquiries, I do not know how to compute the discriminant nor do I know the connection between the multiplicity and discriminant for the quartic polynomial.

Comment: Perhaps you should read that Wikipedia page you linked in your question first. You'll find a lot of connections to the problem you're attempting - this sort of research should be done before asking.

Comment: @KReiser I have extensively, I understand that you may consider my question very lowly but posting here is my last resort. Its fine if no one can provide any help.

Comment: The problem isn't that it's "lowly", it's that you haven't met the expectations of the site. Go back, reread the [no-clue question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27923/how-to-prevent-no-clue-questions) link, and improve your post with some of the information mentioned there (context, definitions, etc) and there will be many people, including me, who will be happy to help you.

Comment: @KReiser I added bunch of comments and definitions. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An explicit expression of the discriminant as explained in the Wikipedia article you have browsed is under the form of the determinant of the following matrix, obtained by collecting the coefficients of

- degree 4 polynomial $p(x)=x^4+0x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ and those of its
- degree 3 derivative $p'(x)=4x^3+0x^2+2ax+b$,

and arranging them in successive rows with shifts, 3 times for the coefficients of $p(x)$ and $4$ times for those of $p'(x)$ (number of times = the degree of the other polynomial):

$$D=\begin{pmatrix}
 1&   0&   a&   b& c&   0  &0\\
 0& 1&   0&   a&   b& c&   0\\
 0& 0&   1&   0&   a&   b& c\\
 4& 0& 2a&   b&   0&   0&   0\\
 0& 4&   0& 2a&   b&   0&   0\\
 0& 0&   4&   0& 2a&   b&   0\\
 0& 0&   0&   4&   0& 2a&   b\\
\end{pmatrix}\tag{1}$$

The 3D surface you are asked to find has equation $\det(D)=0$, i.e., using a Computer Algebra System

$$16a^4c - 4a^3b^2 - 128a^2c^2 + 144ab^2c - 27b^4 + 256c^3=0\tag{2}$$

If you take $b$ as the main variable, i.e., if you write equation (2) under the form:

$$-27b^4 + 4a(36c-a^2)b^2 + 16c(a^4 - 8a^2c + 16c^2)=0.$$

Setting $B=b^2$, one recognizes a quadratic equation:

$$-27B^2 + 4a(36c-a^2)B + 16c(a^4 - 8a^2c + 16c^2)=0\tag{3}$$

Solving (3) gives 2 roots:

$$B_1,B_2=\dfrac{2}{27}((36ac-a^3) \pm (a^2+12c)^{3/2})$$

In a second step, one comes back return to variable $b$, getting finally 4 expressions :

$$b=\sqrt{B_1}, \ \ b=-\sqrt{B_1}, \ \ b=\sqrt{B_2}, \ \ b=-\sqrt{B_2}$$

each one being an equation of a part of the surface you are asked to produce.

Edit: here is this (self intersecting) surface (**caution:** the vertical plane $b=0$ is spurious; it is an artefact of construction):

[image]

*Fig. 1: Graphical representation of equation (2) with semi-transparency: a so-called "swallow-tail". Direction of increasing $a,b,c$ is resp. NW-SE,SW-NE and South-North.*

Here is the Matlab program I have written for its generation :

```
 clear all;close all;hold on; axis equal
 [a,c]=meshgrid(-12:0.1:8);Z=zeros(size(a));
 H=36*a.*c-a.^3;
 I=max(a.^2+12*c,Z);J=I>0;
 B1=J.*max((H + I.^(3/2))*(2/27),Z);
 B2=J.*max((H - I.^(3/2))*(2/27),Z);
 b11=sqrt(B1);b12=-b11;
 b21=sqrt(B2);b22=-b21;
 xlabel('a');ylabel('b');zlabel('c');
 surf(a,b11,c,'edgecolor','none');
 surf(a,b12,c,'edgecolor','none')
 surf(a,b21,c,'edgecolor','none')
 surf(a,b22,c,'edgecolor','none')
 view([33,33]);
```

Remark : I just realized that the figure above was given as the second figure in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant).

**Remark 1**: An excellent [reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0211281.pdf) for this kind of issues.

**Remark 2**: Expression (1) can be found as well [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2280272).

**Remark 3**: I am surprized you are assigned such a task, without having done progressive work on this subject. Besides, I am still asking myself how the polynomial $(x-t)^3(x+3t)$ can help with this question.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I must admit, that I am not very much familiar with any "computer algebra system" so I must say how did you get from 1 to 2? and furthermore, I am also still confused how the hint is supposed to help. Plus the final 4 expressions that you provided, are definitely helpful but I still need to somehow sketch this surface.

Comment: Thank you very much, that would be extremely helpful!

Comment: (1) $\to $ (2) : I used the C.A.S. available with Matlab. You could also obtain it using Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Yes but the figure you provided has given me a lot of insight forsure.

Comment: I have added semi-transparency in order to better visualize the surface.